# Проверить на наличие русских символов и пробела в строке?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

поле проверить форму на корректное заполнение. 
поле может содержать только русские слова пробела и дефисы

- был такое вариант `/^[а-яё]*$/i` но ругается на пробелы
- этот вариант `/^[А-Яа-яё\s]/ui` не ругается, но принимает строку если
  на начинается с русских символов а дальше не чувствителен к раскладке

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте

```
/^[а-яё\s-]+$/i
```

или

```
/^[а-яА-ЯёЁ\s-]+$/
```

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[а-яё\s-]+` - одна и более русских букв, дефисов или пробельных символов
- `$` - конец строки

JS-демо:

```js
var strs = ['Абв', 'А бв', 'Абв-г', 'Абв1'];
var rx = /^[а-яё\s-]+$/i;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

Comment: а как я могу включить сюда дефис? проверка на имена а там часто бывают Бесстужевы-Рюмины, Петровы-Водкины и Муравьевы-Апостолы

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов Смотря какие у вас требования к шаблону. Если все равно, где этот дефис должен быть, то проще простого - `/^[а-яА-ЯёЁ\s-]+$/`. А можно и ``/^[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+(?:[\s-][а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)*$/``

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте `/^[А-Яа-яё\s]{1,}/ui`

Comment: нет, неподходит вот пример киvrtvtbt пропускает